# How to delete unknown partitions

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, gparted

Several months ago, I installed Ubuntu 16.04 but wrecked my grub due to using a 3rd-party boot menu editor. I had to reinstall Windows and Ubuntu. Now sdb5 and sdb6 are unknown partitions. I tried deleting them with gparted but get a message saying I must delete any partitions above sdb6 first, but sdb7 & sdb8 are my primary linux. How can I get rid of these two partitions without losing my os?

[image: GParted Partitions]

Comment: Just use fdisk.  
`sudo fdisk /dev/sdb`
then type d, and select the appropriate partition (sorry, can't test for you... I think d allows you to delete extended partitions).  fdisk doesn't care about disk order, gparted is just bing a bit too pedantic.

Comment: You could also just fix the drive order, and then use gparted to delete the two last partition.  https://journalxtra.com/linux/how-to-reorder-linux-drive-partition-numbers/ tells you how to do that.  (Did not test)

From what I understand from your description, gparted just doesn't like unordered partitions.

Comment: You show the little key icons, showing mounted partitions. Gparted cannot rewrite partition table if any partition is mounted on same drive. And often when using live isntaller, it mounts swap and you have to swapoff to unmount swap also. Then you will be able to edit partitions.

Answer (score 0):

Boot using Ubuntu Live USB and from the Live Session open GParted. Select the drive containing Ubuntu installation from the Gparted dropdown.

[image: dropdown of gparted]

Note the device name of it. Whether it is `/dev/sda` or `/dev/sdb` or `/dev/sdc` etc. Most probably, your booted USB would be recognized as *sdb* and the internal drive as *sda*, but it may vary.

Now since you booted from different drive than you should be able to delete those unknown partitions. Delete them. Create partitions in those free space if you want.

Then before leaving Live session (This is important) reinstall grub. To do so, Click on the right partition icon of your existing Ubuntu installation from Files to mount it, If you aren't sure which partition it was mount every partition until you see one which contains folders with name *boot*, *bin*, *dev*, *etc*, *usr*, *var* etc. This is your Ubuntu installation (unless you have multiple Linux installation). Now, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> to see the location of this mount point in *Files*. Copy it.

Then open a terminal and use

```
sudo grub-install --boot-directory=your-copied-location-here/boot/grub /dev/sda
```

*your-copied-location-here* is the actual location of the mount point of the Ubuntu installation you copied from previous step earlier.

See this article from CommunityWiki about reinstalling Grub - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing

Comment: I don't think this replies the question.  It's about /dev/sdb5 and /dev/sdb6 that can't be deleted.  They're definitely not in use and from what I understand John has a working Ubuntu installation on it /dev/sdb8 for / and /dev/sdb7 for swap.  This is almost certainly caused by non-sequential partitions (which is totally acceptable, but many programs choke on it)

Comment: I myself experienced same problem and got solution using Live USB. On the other hand, trying to change partition order on the same disk Where root partition resides can have bad consequence.

Comment: Only if it's not Ubuntu (or any modern distro, really), because default Ubuntu will use UUID in /etc/fstab and if you're Using LVM, it will use the LVM names, that are immune to renumbering.

Comment: I was able to boot from live USB, swapoff sdb7, and delete the unused partitions. I was able to swapon the swap, but I'm having trouble mounting ext4, which is now sdb6. I can't find anywhere to let me do that...

Comment: So, I'm still in the live USB, looking at /dev/sdc6 in Nautilus, which is what my ext4 partition is now labelled, and having no luck. When I try to mount it in the terminal, I get the error: "can't find /dev/sdc6 in etc/fstab."

Comment: check the updated answer